# Chrome debugger not showing Javascript in aspx files

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, debugging

Chrome (and Canary) used to be able to show javascript source which was embedded in aspx files.

Typically, I would add a `debugger;` statement, save, and then load my web page in Chrome with the developer tools window open. When Chrome hit the `debugger;` statement, it would stop and then show the javascript source, so that I could inspect variable or step through code.

A recent change has changed this so that now, when the `debugger;` statement is executed, Chrome dutifully stops execution but it is unable to show the source.

Does anyone know what has changed; if there are any configuration settings which would re-enable the previous behavior; or how to make this work correctly?

Chrome version: 50.0.2661.102 m (on Windows).
I'm also seeing this in version 53.0.2763.0 canary (64-bit)

I suspect this applies to any kind of embedded script, not just aspx.

Comment: Chrome for windows is up to version **51.0.2704.84 m**, try updating?

Comment: When stuff happens like that to me, it is normally a memory issue and restarting the browser usually clears it up. But if you are seeing it on two different browsers that is strange.

Comment: Version 51.0.2704.84 m -- same result.

Comment: Unlikely a memory issue; I also run Chrome on another computer (Mac) connection across network. While Chrome used to be able to display the source; this time there was no visible source after the break point was hit. It is almost as if Chrome lost the ability to show embedded javascript.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. When I clicked on the aspx page, under the Sources tab, I got a blank page.
What worked for me was refreshing the page in Chrome.
After that, the aspx code showed up in Developer Tools, and I was able to see , debug and search the code. This seems to be a Chrome bug.

[Chrome Developer tool: html script is blank (in source) debugging tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196795/chrome-developer-tool-html-script-is-blank-in-source-debugging-tutorial)

Comment: I tried the same in chrome but did not work. But the same solution worked for me in Microsoft Edge browser.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196795/chrome-developer-tool-html-script-is-blank-in-source-debugging-tutorial) or in @live-love answer helps, it probably means **the aspx page is somehow broken - although not necessarily in a visual way.**

Once you fix the issue, the code will appear on devtools as usual.

To give an example from my own experience on how tricky it may be:

- Somewhere in my `<script>` code, I commented out this kind of code:

  ```
  // var items = { results: <asp:literal runat="server" id="items" /> };
  ```
- I haven't noticed that this `Literal` control is still present in the `designer.cs` file
- In the codebehind, this `Literal`'s `Text` property was set with a valid json value - but that json value was huge (which is why I commented out the above code in the first place).

Something in the combination of the above bullets seems to have broken the aspx. When the codebehind code was also removed, the aspx code was visible again on devtools.